# Using typescript 4 module in typescript 3.7 makes error when compiling

Tags: typescript

My react cra project is using Typescript 3.7 as dependencies. However, the npm lib, `@reduxjs/toolkit`, is using version 4.2. Syntax `import type` is not compatible.

I have tried adding `"exclude": ["**/node_modules"]` and `skipLibCheck:true` to `tsconfig.json`. Not work, plz give some help

```
TypeScript error in /Users/wolwo/repo/yyw-mobile/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/utils.d.ts(1,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

  > 1 | import type { Middleware } from 'redux';
      |             ^
    2 | export declare function getTimeMeasureUtils(maxDelay: number, fnName: string): {
    3 |     measureTime<T>(fn: () => T): T;
    4 |     warnIfExceeded(): void;

/Users/wolwo/repo/yyw-mobile/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/utils.d.ts
TypeScript error in /Users/wolwo/repo/yyw-mobile/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/utils.d.ts(1,33):
';' expected.  TS1005

  > 1 | import type { Middleware } from 'redux';
      |                                 ^
    2 | export declare function getTimeMeasureUtils(maxDelay: number, fnName: string): {
    3 |     measureTime<T>(fn: () => T): T;
    4 |     warnIfExceeded(): void;

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Answer (score 0):

'Import type' only became available in Typescript 3.8. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

You've got two choices:

1. Upgrade to TS 3.8 or above.
2. Write a post-install script that searches through node_modules and replaces 'import type' with 'import' in any Typescript files it finds. It's a bit of a bodge but should work.

If your TS config has noEmitOnError set to false then you might find it is still producing runnable Javascript despite the compilation errors.